# E2E Testing a frontend and mock a request the backend is making with Cypress

Tags: testing, mocking, cypress, e2e-testing

Currently when creating a customer during an e2e testcase, my stripe-like payment gateway says "Customer already exists" which is true because this testcase has been run once already.

What is the high level solution? If it would be a unit test, I think mocking the payment-provider request would be the way to go. But in this case I can only intercept the requests that go from my frontend, right? I could mock away the whole request to my backend but that's not the point of e2e testing I think.

I also thought about some sort of flag or environment variable so that the backend knows if it's currently e2e tested (and in this case behave differently, eg not make this specific request). But I think that's not good practice.

Comment: Each test should set up and tear down all of the data that’s required to complete the test, so when the test runs, it should have a clean state to start from. If your test is failing because the customer already exists then you should be removing the customer from the database or set the database to some clean state before the test starts.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out something. I think e2e should test the integrated services too, like the integration between my backend and the payment gateway.

When the test starts, I modify the email (which was the duplicate key for the payment provider) by doing the following little code snippet. Works for now and I think it's not that bad:

`` user.email = user.email.split("@").join(`${Date.now()}@`); ``